# Having trouble understanding directory navigation with os.walk

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to python and I'm trying my hand at a weekend project. I want to navigate through my music directories and get the artist name of each music file and export that to a csv so that I can upgrade my music collection (a lot of it is from when I was younger and didn't care about quality).

Anyway, I'm trying to get the path of each music file in its respective directory, so I can pass it to id3 tag reading module to get the artist name.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
import os

def main():
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".mp3") or file.endswith(".m4a"):
                print(os.path.abspath(file))
```

However, .abspath() doesn't do what I think it should. If I have a directory like this:

```
music
--1.mp3
--2.mp3
--folder
----a.mp3
----b.mp3
----c.mp3
----d.m4a
----e.m4a
```

and I run my code, I get this output:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\python_music\1.mp3
C:\Users\User\Documents\python_music\2.mp3
C:\Users\User\Documents\python_music\a.mp3
C:\Users\User\Documents\python_music\b.mp3
C:\Users\User\Documents\python_music\c.mp3
C:\Users\User\Documents\python_music\d.m4a
C:\Users\User\Documents\python_music\e.m4a
```

I'm confused why it doesn't show the 5 files being inside of a folder. 
Aside from that, am I even going about this in the easiest or best way? Again, I'm new to python so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should add some prints and it will make it pretty obvious what is happening.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing *just* the filename to `os.path.abspath()`, which has no context but your current working directory.

Join the path with the `subdir` parameter:

```
print(os.path.join(subdir, file))
```

From the [`os.path.abspath()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath):

> On most platforms, this is equivalent to calling the function `normpath()` as follows: `normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))`.

so if your current working directory is `C:\Users\User\Documents\python_music` all your files are joined relative to that.

But `os.walk` gives you the correct location to base filenames off instead; from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

> For each directory in the tree rooted at directory *top* (including *top* itself), it yields a 3-tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`.
>
> *dirpath* is a string, the path to the directory. *[...]* *filenames* is a list of the names of the non-directory files in *dirpath*. **Note that the names in the lists contain no path components. To get a full path (which begins with *top*) to a file or directory in *dirpath*, do `os.path.join(dirpath, name)`.**

Emphasis mine.